# Stored procedure - counting rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I'm learning procedures now (MySQL) and I just created to myself a little project to get to play with it, but is not working. This is what I'm trying to accomplish: Count how many employees there are in total by counting the social security number, because more than one person can have the same name right? So I created this proc. :

```
drop procedure if exists out_count_employees;

delimiter ^^
create procedure out_count_employees (IN Social_S_N char(9), OUT SumTotal int)
begin

    select COUNT(dno)
    into SumTotal
    from employee
    where Social_S_N = ssn;


end ^^
delimiter ;


call out_count_employees('ssn', @SumTotal);

select @SumTotal;
```

I saw an example where they were using the COUNT but it's not working in this case...

the table name is employee, the field I'm using is ssn which stores int only of max length 9

Thanks for the help

Comment: EDIT: the field ssn on table employee is a char

Comment: I modified it a little but still doesn't work:

 declare SumTotal char(100);
    
 select COUNT(Social_S_N)
    into SumTotal
    from employee
 where Social_S_N = ssn;

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: If you want to count the total number of employees, you shouldn't have a `WHERE` clause. You're just counting how many employees have a specific SSN. And the SSN you're giving as a parameter isn't even valid, so the count will be `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The where clause should not go there, that only counts a number of the employees. Try using into:

drop procedure if exists out_count_employees;

```
delimiter ^^
create procedure out_count_employees (IN Social_S_N char(9), OUT SumTotal int)
begin

    select COUNT(*)
    into SumTotal
    from employee;    

end ^^
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the total number of employees, you shouldn't have a `WHERE` clause, and there's no need for the `Social_S_N` parameter. Just use `COUNT(*)`.

```
create procedure out_count_employees (OUT SumTotal int)
begin
    select COUNT(*)
    into SumTotal
    from employee;
end ^^
```

You don't need to worry about employees with the same name, you're just counting the number of rows in the table.